# phpmyadmin: why Export does not save to specified SaveDir?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

With mysql 5.7 and phpmyadmin 4.8 (and php 7.2) under macOS 10.14...

My config.inc.php includes:

```
 $cfg['SaveDir'] = '/Users/me/Databases/mysql/saves';
```

When from phpmyadmin I Export a database, I have checked option:

```
 Save on server in the directory /Users/me/Databases/mysql/saves/
```

And that directory has permissions (shown by ls -ld /Users/me/Databases/mysql/saves):

```
 drwxr-xr-x  2 _mysql  _mysql
```

Nonetheless, when I do the export, it saves the .sql file to

```
 /Users/me/Downloads
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The SaveDir directive points to a folder that phpMyAdmin (through the webserver process) writes to, not MySQL. It appears as if your permissions allow access for the mysql daemon, but not the web server. Set the owner and group to those used by the webserver. If you're having trouble determining those, you could TEMPORARILY set permissions on the folder to 777, write a file, and examine the created file; the permissions it's created with are the same combination you'll need to allow access for that directory.

Comment: The web server is a localhost using apache 2. How do I determine what owner & group are "used by" that?

Comment: You could TEMPORARILY set permissions on the `/Users/me/Databases/mysql/saves` folder to 777, export a file, and examine the created file; the permissions it's created with are the same combination you'll need to allow access for that directory.

Comment: Tried `sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/me/Databases/mysql/saves`. But no matter whether in phpmyadmin I export with the Quick method or Custom method,in either case selecting option "Save on server in the directory /Users/me/Databases/mysql/saves/", after I press the Go button I'm taken in phpmyadmin to a new long page showing all possible options, and if I click the Go button there...no export file is saved anywhere!